# How to host ASP.NET API on Amazon Web Services (AWS)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I want to create a facade API that sits behind AWS. I want to create a REST API with **ASP.NET Web API 2**. I want to use AWS for scaling and authentication. The facade API will call other APIs.  I'm new to cloud hosting and AWS. I have been reading documentations and doing online searches but I'm not sure what infrastructure I need to get started.

Do I need an AWS Gateway and an EC2 instance as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/?hp=tile)? I've came across some tutorials that says to use Elastic Beanstalk. Or do I just need a EC2 instance?  I don't know where to start so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an EC2 instance, but that won't scale automatically. If you use Elastic Beanstalk it will manage the EC2 instances, autoscaling groups and load balancer to handle scaling for you. EB will also manage deployments for you among other things.

You can put AWS API Gateway in front of your API in order to handle authentication, caching and rate-limiting among other things.

Comment: Would Gateway handle my scaling needs? Or is that only available with EB?

Comment: EB will scale out the number of EC2 instances based on load, and distribute the requests across those instances using an ELB. API Gateway will cache API responses to help reduce the load that your EB application ultimately has to handle.

Comment: Thanks! And for others, I have this great guide https://www.expeditedssl.com/aws-in-plain-english